# Python Poetry and Script Entrypoints

Tags: python, python-poetry

Im trying to use Poetry and the scripts option to run a script. Like so:

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
xyz = "src.cli:main"
```

Folder layout

```
   .
    ├── poetry.lock
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── run-book.txt
    └── src
        ├── __init__.py
        └── cli.py
```

I then perform an install like so:

```
❯ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

If I then try and run the command its not found (?)

```
❯ xyz
zsh: command not found: xyz
```

Am i missing something here! Thanks,

Comment: `poetry run xyz`. And then otherwise you need to actually install the project somewhere that is accessible globally for your own user account or all user accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poetry is likely installing the script in your user local directory. On Ubuntu, for example, this is `$HOME/.local/bin`. If that directory isn't in your path, your shell will not find the script.

A side note: It is generally a good idea to put a subdirectory with your package name in the `src` directory. It's generally better to not have an `__init__.py` in your `src` directory. Also consider renaming `cli.py` to `__main__.py`. This will allow your package to be run as a script using `python -m package_name`.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything right besides not activating the virtual environment or running that alias (`xyz`) via `poerty run xyz`. One can activate the virtualenv via `poetry shell`. Afterwards, `xyz` should run from your shell.

PS: [@jisrael18's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656210) is totally right. Normally one would have another folder (which is your main Python module) inside the `src` folder.

```bash
.
├── src
│   └── pyproj
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __main__.py
...
```

Comment: With this `src` layout, would "src.cli:main" change to "pyproj:main" now?

Comment: If `src` is in your `PYTHONPATH` (`sys.path`) then yes.