# Python ModuleNotFoundError only in command line execution not in IDE

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, modulenotfounderror

I see a `ModuleNotFoundError` error when running a simple program.

The project is created using Poetry, and the setup is as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

`h.py` has this:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
```

`s.py` has this:

```
from src.helper.h import add


def main():
    print(add(1, 2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I execute the code from within PyCharm IDE, I see the output correctly. If I execute from command line using `python3 src/scripts/s.py`, I see an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/dev/python-learn/src/scripts/s.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.helper.h import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I tried adding `__init.py__` to each of the directories `src`, `helpers`, and `scripts`. That did not resolve the issue.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: This may help: [python-poetry-and-script-entrypoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654589/python-poetry-and-script-entrypoints)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding the following in the `pyproject.toml` file

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
script1 = "src.scripts.script1:main"
```

and running it as

```
poetry run script1
```

Answer (score 1):

try `poetry run python3 [your_script].py`

although poetry has initialized your project and you may have run `poetry install`, you are not necessarily utilizing the poetry environment when you directly run `python3 src/scripts/s.py`

there are two main ways to access the poetry environment:

1. inline, as i mention above
2. by activating a persistent poetry shell. see more info [here in the poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#activating-the-virtual-environment)